# Unknown possibly handmade glassware- description in information below

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, equipment, pharmacology

Okay, Another random item from the cupboard (unknown users or discipline of life sciences unknown) could be anything up to 40 years old....

This appears to be a 2 neck quickfit adapter (B19 and B14) leading to a long narrow tube which loops back on itself then loops again into a closed vessel. None of the other technicians can remember using this item but some of the items do look certainly altered by a glassblower if not entirely made by a glassblower. Whole item is 30cm in length...

Any thoughts on what it could be used for or what it might be?[image]

Comment: Just a guess, but it looks like it might be for preparing and transporting an air-sensitive sample/reaction. The sample is in the bulb and liquid is in the loop to create a trap. With the liquid in place, you could open the top and connect to something else without exposing your sample to very much air.

Comment: I agree with @Andrew.   Thanks for sharing OP, I love seeing bits of odd and unique chemistry glassware.

Comment: Interesting idea thank you Andrew! I will relay to the team and Academics and see if they can be useful or not!

Comment: Michael we have a lot more that I haven't taken photographs of and put up yet so there will be more odd and unique chemistry glassware to come!